# Google Pay API get the charged amount

Tags: android, google-pay

I am following the tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial) to integrate google pay API to obtain funds for my app. So far I have successfully managed to make charging but I am finding it very hard to get the charged amount on successful transfer.

The google wallet dependency I am using is

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:15.0.1'
```

I want to get the charged amount in `MainActivity`'s`onActivityResult` as I make the request from another `Fragment` . But the `Intent data` has only the Email address and billing status. The only logical way I can think of is to somehow inject the charged amount manullay to `Intent data` but I can't seem to find a way around.

I tried to set a parameter here but It doesn't show up in the `Intent` I receive in the `onActivityResult`.

Can anyone give me a hand here?

```
public void requestPayment(BigDecimal amount) {
        // Disables the button to prevent multiple clicks.
        //mGooglePayButton.setClickable(false);

        // The price provided to the API should include taxes and shipping.
        // This price is not displayed to the user.

        String chargeAmount = amount.divide(MICROS).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toString();

//        String price = PaymentsUtil.microsToString(chargeAmount);

        TransactionInfo transaction = PaymentsUtil.createTransaction(chargeAmount);

        Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
        parcel.writeString(chargeAmount);
        parcel.recycle();
        transaction.writeToParcel(parcel, 0);

        PaymentDataRequest request = PaymentsUtil.createPaymentDataRequest(transaction);

        Task<PaymentData> futurePaymentData = mPaymentsClient.loadPaymentData(request);


        // Since loadPaymentData may show the UI asking the user to select a payment method, we use
        // AutoResolveHelper to wait for the user interacting with it. Once completed,
        // onActivityResult will be called with the result.
        AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(futurePaymentData, Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()), LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);


    }
```

Comment: The amount is something set by you, I don't understand where you're trying to get it from?

Comment: @fstanis Well. Amount is set in a fragmet. Im trying to access it in the MainActivity's onActivityResult

Comment: @Fawzan where are you setting email address and payment status?

Comment: @VicJordan I am not setting it. Google wallet intent sets them and returns the result.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the retrieval of the payment token does not imply that a payment transaction happened successfully. This is something that only happens when you submit your order for processing through your payment processor or gateway. When that happens, this typically includes an order id and final charged amount.

I'd suggest this as a more specific way to account for successful transactions.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment that Email and Payment Status is set by Google Wallet so I am not sure if you can modify that Intent.

**Solution:**

One option is to use `sharedPreference` for this purpose. In `requestPayment()` method set `chargeAmount` in `SharedPreference` and in `MainActivity#onActivityResult()` if payment is successful get `chargeAmount` from `SharedPreference`. You are done.

```
public void requestPayment(BigDecimal amount) {

    ...........

    String chargeAmount = amount.divide(MICROS).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toString();
    // set chargeAmount to SharedPreference here

    .............
}
```

**MainActivity#onActivityResult()**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    // get chargeAmount from SharedPreference here 
                    PaymentData paymentData = PaymentData.getFromIntent(data);
                    String token = paymentData.getPaymentMethodToken().getToken();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    break;
                case AutoResolveHelper.RESULT_ERROR:
                    Status status = AutoResolveHelper.getStatusFromIntent(data);
                    // Log the status for debugging.
                    // Generally, there is no need to show an error to
                    // the user as the Google Pay API will do that.
                    break;
                default:
                    // Do nothing.
            }
            break;
        default:
            // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: If I do have a way to associate the transaction Id with the shared preference entry I'd definitely do this. But I cannot do it. Because I have Async tasks running different requests. I don't want to have ambiguity while reading the value from the shared-preference.